# How to test two Infinispan with JUnit?

Tags: spring, junit, infinispan

I want to create test to make sure two instances of Infinispan cache are communication well.

In first step I create two applicationContexts using two different application-test.properties

In logs I can see two instances of cache are created.
In debug I can see also two different instances of CacheManager | DefaultCacheManager.

Everything looks fine - but when I add some valued to one instance second one instance of Cache (Infinispan) is not notified about that.

Any advice?

Comment: solution of my problem is:

 System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
 System.setProperty("jgroups.bind_addr", "GLOBAL");

and **do not use 127.0.0.1** - instead I am using: HostUtils.getHostName()

Comment: There is also solution for problems with interaction between multiple instances of cache. The issue is related to JGroups used to communication between caches (Infinispan). Solution is to use different **channel** in different tests.

Answer (score 4):

Currently you can use NoSQLUnit https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit#infinispan-engine which gives support for testing and managing lifecycle of Infinispan.

In next weeks we are going to integrate this to Arquillian APE as well.

If you have any question don't hesitate to ping me, my twitter is @alexsotob

Comment: A couple of days ago I added a [demo](https://githnfub.com/infinispan-demos/infinispan-nosqlunit-demo) on how to test Infinispan with NoSQLUnit :)

Answer (score 0):

1. if you have problem with start two Infinispan's caches on local machine try to use real host name or IP instead 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'
2. if you have problem with multiple JUnit tests and Infinispan's caches try to stop transport after each test - like:

   > @After
   >
   > public void tearDown() {
   >
   > ```
   > applicationContext.getBean(CacheManager.class).getTransport().stop();
   > ```
   >
   > }

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file infinispan.xml

   < infinispan
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.1.xsd"
       xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.1">

   ```
   <namedCache name="xml-configured-cache">
           <eviction strategy="LIRS" maxEntries="10" />
   </namedCache>
   ```

   < / infinispan >
2. Init cache with file configuration:

Cahe c = new DefaultCacheManager("infinispan.xml").getCache("xml-configured-cache");

That's all!